# The method parseLong(String) in the type Long is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert String variable to long array with charAt, but I have problem.

```
public class PESEL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long[] PESEL = new long[11];
        String PESELString;

        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
        PESELString = odczyt.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < PESELString.length(); i++){
        PESEL[i] = Long.parseLong(PESELString.charAt(i));
        }


    }

}
```

In the for loop, i have alert: The method parseLong(String) in the type Long is not applicable for the arguments (char). Why parseLong is not applicable for the arguments char?
Thanks.

Comment: Is a `char` a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because [Long#parseLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) only accepts `String`

```
PESEL[i] = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(PESELString.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Way you use `long` for one digit?
Any way, you can do this without explicit conversion (also for `int` and `short`) if you have sure there are only digits...

```
PESEL[i] = PESELString.charAt(i) - 48;
```